# Storing words into an array in Mars MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm trying to teach myself Assembly using Mars for the MIPS architecture and am wondering how to store a series of words into an array.

I know that if I have 4 words, I'd allocate 16 bytes like so:

```
.data
X: .space 16
```

I then have some words:

```
.data
X:       .space 16
Ryan:    .asciiz "Ryan"
Tammi:   .asciiz "Tammi"
Mike:    .asciiz "Mike"
Jessica: .asciiz "Jessica"
```

Now, if I want to assign X[0] to Ryan, X[1] to Tammi, etc, do I first load the array address into $a0, then load the words into temp registers? I'm not quite sure how to assign the values to their respective indexes and then print the values to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need to do it at runtime, you can of course just initialize your array with the pointers directly:

```
.data
X:       .word Ryan, Tammi, Mike, Jessica
Ryan:    .asciiz "Ryan"
Tammi:   .asciiz "Tammi"
Mike:    .asciiz "Mike"
Jessica: .asciiz "Jessica"
```

Otherwise you'd have to manually do the assignment at runtime, such as:

```
la $t0, X
la $t1, Ryan
sw $t1, ($t0)
la $t1, Tammi
sw $t1, 4($t0)
la $t1, Mike
sw $t1, 8($t0)
la $t1, Jessica
sw $t1, 12($t0)
```

Subsequently you can print them using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Loved this solution, for me I used the first solution, just wanted to add how to print it:

```
.data

array_temperaturas: .space 20 
array_cidades: .word cidade_1, cidade_2, cidade_3, cidade_4, cidade_5
cidade_1: .asciiz "Porto"
cidade_2: .asciiz "Lisboa"
cidade_3: .asciiz "Faro"
cidade_4: .asciiz "Coimbra"
cidade_5: .asciiz "Viseu"

.text
# Index arrays = 0
addi $t0, $zero, 0

# Get word in index $t0
lw $t7, array_cidades($t0)

    li $v0, 4
    move $a0, $t7
    syscall
```

Basically just used lw to the $t7 register at array_cidades($t0) and used a basic print string call